# Top ten tags ala Delicious

Tags: tags

How would I create a list that only shows the ten most used tags for my site?  Kind of how Delicious organizes tags.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with [`get_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags). Basic idea would be something like this:

```
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'number' => 10,
        );

$tags = get_tags( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks! That with a foreach loop to generate the html did the trick.